# How to separate an NSString by two special characters?

Tags: nsstring, nsarray

i have a string and need to split it into multiple strings.
for example this is my string:

#titleone% &apple* #titletwo% &honey*

each time it reads "#" i need it to save the string in an array and stop when it read "%". Also each time it read "&" i need to save the string in another array and stop when it read "*".
so far iv done this

```
NSString* foo = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray* stringComponents = [foo componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSArray* otherstringComponents = [foo componentsSeparatedByString:@"%"];
```

i just need to know how to add to an array each time it read a certain character and stop each time it reads another character.
or if there is another way to do the job then i will appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You're better of using `NSScanner` and scanning up to your set of start characters (using `scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:`) and then checking which start character it is to decide what to do with the string obtained from scanning unto the end character.